# Как грамотно построить класс-рендерер?

Tags: c++, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, opengles

У меня есть проект, в котором имеются классы: `View`, `Scene`, `Item` и `Renderer`. Тобишь у меня есть некая сцена, которую я отображаю во вью вместе с доступными в заданном пространстве итемами. Для прорисовки используется `opengles`, вызовы которого скрыты за методами класса `Renderer`, который управляет `opengl` программами, шейдерами а также отрисовывает текстуры.

Изначально все было построено так: `View` выясняет у `Scene` какие `Item`-s видны и передает ему уже сконфигурированный объект класса `Renderer` в метод `render`. В этом методе `Item` просто дергает нужный метод из `Renderer` (вроде `renderRing`). После всего этого буферы свапаются и мы видим изображение. Однако это не оптимально из-за того, что в на `gpu` каждый раз передаются данные, которые уже были переданы до этого (к тому каждый раз происходят вычисления, вроде триангуляции, что тоже плохо). Чтобы избежать этого я создал класс `Cache` который использует VAO для обращения к уже переданным на GPU данным. Теперь методы `Renderer` возвращают `Cache` который мы можем сохранить и использовать для рендеринга в дальнейшем. Но это оказалось плохой идеей: дело в том, что если мы имеем несколько `View` то `Cache` все равно будет создан только один раз (так как сцена все равно одна), а из-за этого во втором `View` картинка не может быть прорисована (так как там другой `Renderer` с другой программой.

Как правильно организовать класс `Renderer` исходя из вышеизложенного? Следует также учесть, что классы `View` и `Item` изначально абстрактные и количество наследников нам изначально не может быть известно (соответсвенно я не могу для `Renderer` сдесь применить визитера). Я полагаю, что необходимо хранить `Cache` не в итемах, а именно в `Renderer` (что позволит использовать несколько `View`), но не могу понять как это правильно организовать.

Comment: Renderer должен быть один (и, соответственно, один кэш), если вы все рисуете одинаково. А вот View может быть много.